# Difference between _locals and locals in express 4.0

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

For some reason in my jade files I can access files set with _locals and not locals?:

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    if(req.isAuthenticated()) //true
    {
        res.locals.user = req.user;
    }else {
        res.locals.user = null;
    }
}
```

**Jade**

```
-console.info(_locals.user); //{_id: 5775.....4343}
-console.info(locals.user); //undefined
-console.info(user); //null
```

Comment: `_locals` is an internal name that Jade uses when rewriting your variables; try `console.info(user)`.

Comment: Ye, ok I've updated the question as I didn't think it was relevant before. I thought it was too specific to me that it wouldn't be worth posting the whole issue. But how can using `user = null` when using it as you suggest? :/

Comment: I don’t understand what you’re asking. Jade will rewrite `user` so that it refers to `_locals.user`, unless you’ve defined a variable called `user` inside your template.

Comment: Your speed is amazing thanks :) I just realise that I was passing a variable of `user` to the jade through my render. I hadn't thought about it before. Also sorry the question wasn't clear :)