# locals AND locals._locals (clone) sent from server

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, keystonejs

I've noticed I have a duplicate of my locals received from the server WITHIN my locals. For example

```
Object {
    settings: "4.2", 
    env: "development", 
    utils: true, 
    pretty: true, 
    _locals: {
        settings: "4.2", 
        env: "development", 
        utils: true, 
        pretty: true, 
        posts: {
            0 { title: 'post 1' },
            1 { title: 'post 2' }
        }
    },
    posts: {
        0 { title: 'post 1' },
        1 { title: 'post 2' }
    }
```

I don't believe I've set this anywhere. Why would it be that way, should I remove it, and what is the best way too.

I'm using keystone JS, Express, and Node.

The title to this question is similar but the question itself is different.
[Difference between _locals and locals in express 4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31253666/difference-between-locals-and-locals-in-express-4-0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JS doesn't have any opportunities to hide private members of object. So common practice is start them by _.

It's means that using members started by _, e.g obj._locals, is not correct.

Comment: thanks, do you know why it would be created in the first case?

Comment: I think it's necessary to implement some ability of framework. Don't care about it.